# Unable to change row height

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I wish to use the alpine dark theme and just adjust the row height.

This is the .scss file I import in my component:

```
@import '../../../node_modules/ag-grid-community/src/styles/ag-grid.scss';
@import '../../../node_modules/ag-grid-community/src/styles/ag-theme-alpine-dark/sass/_ag-theme-alpine-dark-mixin.scss';

.ag-theme-alpine-dark {
  @include ag-theme-alpine-dark(
    (
      background-color: red,
      row-height: ag-derived(grid-size, $times: 2, $plus: 1)
    )
  );
}
```

The background colour is displayed, so I know everything is imported correctly.

The default value for `row-height` is `ag-derived(grid-size, $times: 7)` ultimately imported from `node_modules/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine/sass/_ag-theme-alpine-default-params.scss`.

Not sure what this `ag-derived` magic is, or what is the `$times` value is either. I would have thought lowering the `$times` value in my .scss would have an effect on the row-height, but it just seems to change the line-height of the cells.

Also, if I set `row-height: 100px` in my .scss, the row-height stays the same, and the line-heights in the cells change to 98px.

If I set `rowHeight={100}` in the grid properties, then this works, but the line-height remains 40px.

Setting `headerHeight={100}` works as expected - both the height and line-heights are 100px.

In addition I need to amend the floating filter row height, but there does not seem to be a way to do this.

Honestly, I can't understand why this has to be so difficult - really frustrating stuff.

**Edit:**

So to get this working for the moment, I'm setting the following grid properties:

```
floatingFiltersHeight={32}
rowHeight={32}
headerHeight={32}
```

and adding the following to my component's .scss:

```
.ag-cell {
   line-height: 32px;
}
```

Comment: Normally, to overwrite a style come from modules, we first DO write :host ::ng-deep before class declarations. For example=> :host ::ng-deep .ag-theme-balham {  .ag-cell { line-height: 32px; }  }

Comment: Were you able to solve this @J_P?